# React classSet not working - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use `classSet` in `React` to dynamically create some css.  I am just trying to hide a specific link on a dropdown.  Here is my class

```js
define(function(require) {
  'use strict';

  var React = require('react');

  var NavDropdown = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var cx = React.addons.classSet;
      var classes = cx({
        'hidden': true
      });

      return (
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li className="dropdown">
          <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Other <b className="caret"></b></a>
          <ul className="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a className="{classes}" href="#books">Books</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
        );
    }
  });

  return NavDropdown;
});
```

Looking at [this](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html) example on the docs page, this seems fairly trivial and seems like it should be working, but `classes` is not getting interpolated and placed into the dom.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `className` was not supposed to be inside quotes.

It should be the `className={classes}`

NOT `className="{className}"`

And then everything works perfectly.